# Mouse pointer disappears whenever going back from crouton (Elementary OS Freya)

Tags: crouton-os

I installed Elementary OS Freya on a crouton, however when I go back to Chrome OS (while the crouton is running), the mouse pointer wouldn't show up. It's not invisible, it's like there's no mouse attached at all.
If I attach a physical mouse (via USB or BT) I get the pointer to work just fine. I tried to look at the trackpad drivers/settings but I cant figure out what's preventing it from showing on Chrome OS.

Answer (score 0):

Go to tty1 with CTRL + ALT + F1 then get back to desktop with CTRL + ALT + F7

https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7334/the-cursor-mouse-disappears-after-lock